# List of Scala's "magic" functions

Tags: syntax, scala

Where can I find a list of Scala's "magic" functions, such as `apply`, `unapply`, `update`, `+=`, etc.?

By magic-functions I mean functions which are used by some syntactic sugar of the compiler, for example

```
o.update(x,y) <=> o(x) = y
```

I googled for some combination of `scala` `magic` and synonyms of `functions`, but I didn't find anything.

I'm not interested with the *usage* of magic functions in the standard library, but in which magic functions exists.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As far as I know:

Getters/setters related:

```
apply
update
identifier_=
```

Pattern matching:

```
unapply
unapplySeq
```

For-comprehensions:

```
map
flatMap
filter
withFilter
foreach
```

Prefixed operators:

```
unary_+
unary_-
unary_!
unary_~
```

Beyond that, any implicit from A to B. Scala will also convert `A <op>= B` into `A = A <op> B`, if the former operator isn't defined, "op" is not alphanumeric, and `<op>=` isn't `!=`, `==`, `<=` or `>=`.

And I don't believe there's any single place where all of Scala's syntactic sugars are listed.

Comment: You might want to add the unary_! etc. operators that were listed in one of the other posts, since this looks like the most exhaustive answer to the question here :)

Comment: What's `identifier_=`?  Never seen that.

Comment: @StefanEndrullis Try this: `object X { var _x = 0; def x_=(n: Int) { _x = n }; def x = _x }; X.x = 5; println(X.x)`

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral: Ah, OK, `identifier` was just meant to be a placeholder. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there is now one place ;)

Comment: Can you add brief explanation/usages of these also?

Comment: There's also `equals` that is called by `==`

Answer (score 17):

In addition to `update` and `apply`, there are also a number of unary operators which (I believe) qualify as magical:

- `unary_+`
- `unary_-`
- `unary_!`
- `unary_~`

Add to that the regular infix/suffix operators (which can be almost anything) and you've got yourself the complete package.

You really should take a look at the Scala Language Specification.  It is the only authoritative source on this stuff.  It's not that hard to read (as long as you're comfortable with context-free grammars), and very easily searchable.  The only thing it doesn't specify well is the XML support.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry if it's not exactly answering your question, but my favorite WTF moment so far is @ as assignment operator inside pattern match. Thanks to soft copy of "Programming in Scala" I found out what it was pretty quickly.

Using @ we can bind any part of a pattern to a variable, and if the pattern match succeeds, the variable will capture the value of the sub-pattern. Here's the example from **Programming in Scala** (Section 15.2 - Variable Binding):

```
expr match {
  case UnOp("abs", e @ UnOp("abs", _)) => e
  case _ =>
}
```

> If the entire pattern match succeeds,
>   then the portion that matched the
>   UnOp("abs", _) part is made available
>   as variable e.

And [here](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch03.html#BindingNestedVariablesInCaseClauses)'s what **Programming Scala** says about it.

That link no longer works. [Here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-scala-2nd/9781491950135/ch04.html) is one that does.

Comment: Can you share with us what the @ operator does?

Answer (score 4):

I'll also add `_*` for *pattern matching on an arbitrary number of parameters* like

```
case x: A(_*)
```

And *operator associativity* rule, from Odersky-Spoon-Venners book:

> The associativity of an operator in Scala is determined by its last
>   character. As mentioned on <...>, any method that ends
>   in a ‘:’ character is invoked on its right operand, passing in the
>   left operand. Methods that end in any other character are the other
>   way around. They are invoked on their left operand, passing in the
>   right operand. So a * b yields a.*(b), but a ::: b yields b.:::(a).

---

Maybe we should also mention syntactic desugaring of *for expressions* which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754089/scala-for-comprehension)

---

And (of course!), *alternative syntax for pairs*

```
a -> b //converted to (a, b), where a and b are instances
```

(as correctly pointed out, this one is just an *implicit conversion* done through a library, so it's probably not eligible, but I find it's a common puzzler for newcomers)

---

Comment: IIRC `->` is just a library function.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add that there is also a "magic" trait - [`scala.Dynamic`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Dynamic):

> A marker trait that enables dynamic invocations. Instances `x` of this trait allow method invocations `x.meth(args)` for arbitrary method names `meth` and argument lists `args` as well as field accesses `x.field` for arbitrary field names `field`.
>
> If a call is not natively supported by `x` (i.e. if type checking fails), it is rewritten according to the following rules:
>
> ```
> foo.method("blah")      ~~> foo.applyDynamic("method")("blah")
> foo.method(x = "blah")  ~~> foo.applyDynamicNamed("method")(("x", "blah"))
> foo.method(x = 1, 2)    ~~> foo.applyDynamicNamed("method")(("x", 1), ("", 2))
> foo.field           ~~> foo.selectDynamic("field")
> foo.varia = 10      ~~> foo.updateDynamic("varia")(10)
> foo.arr(10) = 13    ~~> foo.selectDynamic("arr").update(10, 13)
> foo.arr(10)         ~~> foo.applyDynamic("arr")(10)
> ```
>
> As of Scala 2.10, defining direct or indirect subclasses of this trait is only possible if the language feature dynamics is enabled.

So you can do stuff like

```
import scala.language.dynamics

object Dyn extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(name: String)(a1: Int, a2: String) {
    println("Invoked " + name + " on (" + a1 + "," + a2 + ")");
  }
}

Dyn.foo(3, "x");
Dyn.bar(3, "y");
```

Answer (score 3):

They are defined in the Scala Language Specification.
As far as I know, there are just three "magic" functions as you mentioned.

Scalas Getter and Setter may also relate to your "magic":

```
scala> class Magic {
 |     private var x :Int = _
 |     override def toString = "Magic(%d)".format(x)
 |     def member = x
 |     def member_=(m :Int){ x = m }
 | }

defined class Magic

scala> val m = new Magic

m: Magic = Magic(0)

scala> m.member

res14: Int = 0

scala> m.member = 100

scala> m

res15: Magic = Magic(100)

scala> m.member += 99

scala> m

res17: Magic = Magic(199)
```

Comment: If you could dig for me an evidence for that claim, you'll be answering my question ;-) I assumed it'll be in the specs, but finding them in it is not a fun job.

Comment: Scala Language Specification:
6.15 Assignments
...
If x is a parameterless function defined in
some template, and the same template contains a setter function x_= as member,
then the assignment x = e is interpreted as the invocation x_=(e ) of that setter
function. Analogously, an assignment f .x = e to a parameterless function x is
interpreted as the invocation f .x_=(e ).
An assignment f (args) = e with a function application to the left of the “=’ operator
is interpreted as f .update(args, e ), i.e. the invocation of an update function
defined by f .

Comment: I ment, evidence that there're no more.