# What are all the instances of syntactic sugar in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar

What are all the instances of syntactic sugar in Scala?

They are hard to search for since most/all of them are purely symbols and are thus hard to search for without knowing the name of the concept.

TODO:

- Implicit conversions
- `_` syntax for anonymous functions
- Other things I'm forgetting

Comment: More TODOs: Tuples, Symbols, XML Literals.

Comment: I dont think XML fits because its not truly sugar in the sense of shorthand of something else. I agree on Tuples and Symbols though.

Comment: If you saw the the code executed to build the XML DOM instances corresponding to an XML literals, I think you'd have to agree the literals are an abbreviation!

Comment: More TODOs: for comprehensions, placeholder syntax for anonymous functions, case classes, val/var on constructor params to generate accessor methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483212/list-of-scalas-magic-functions

"Where can I find a list of scala's "magic" functions, such as apply, unapply, update, += etc? By magic-functions I mean functions which are used by some syntactic sugar of the compiler, "

Comment: Does an if/else expression also have a raw form?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## Basics:

- `a b` is equivalent to `a.b`.
- `a b c` is equivalent to `a.b(c)`, except when `b` ends in `:`. In that case, `a b c` is equivalent to `c.b(a)`.
- `a(b)` is equivalent to `a.apply(b)` This is why the following definitions for an anonymous functions are identical:

  ```
  val square1 = (x: Int) => x*x
  val square2 = new Function1[Int,Int] {
      def apply(x: Int) = x*x
  }
  ```

  When calling `square1(y)`, you are actually calling `square1.apply(y)` which `square1` must have as specified by the `Function1` trait (or `Function2`, etc...)
- `a(b) = c` is equivalent to `a.update(b,c)`. Likewise, `a(b,c) = d` is equivalent to `a.update(b,c,d)` and so on.
- `a.b = c` is equivalent to `a.b_=(c)`. When you create a `val`/`var` `x` in a Class/Object, Scala creates the methods `x` and `x_=` for you. You can define these yourself, but if you define `y_=` you **must** define `y` or it will not compile, for example:

  ```
  scala> val b = new Object{ def set_=(a: Int) = println(a) }
  b: java.lang.Object{def set_=(Int): Unit} = $anon$1@17e4cec

  scala> b.set = 5
  <console>:6: error: value set is not a member of java.lang.Object{def set_=(Int): Unit}
         b.set = 5
           ^

  scala> val c = new Object{ def set = 0 ; def set_=(a:Int) = println(a) }
  c: java.lang.Object{def set: Int; def set_=(Int): Unit} = $anon$1@95a253

  scala> c.set = 5
  5
  ```
- `-a` corresponds to `a.unary_-`. Likewise for `+a`,`~a`, and `!a`.
- `a <operator>= b`, where `<operator>` is some set of special characters, is equivalent to `a = a <operator> b` **only** if `a` doesn't have the `<operator>=` method, for example:

  ```
  class test(val x:Int) {
      def %%(y: Int) = new test(x*y)
  }

  var a = new test(10)
  a.x // 10
  a %%= 5 // Equivalent to a = a %% 5
  a.x // 50
  ```

Comment: so if `foo(bar)` is equivalent to `foo.apply(bar)` then `foo.apply(bar)` should be equivalent to `foo.apply.apply(bar)`, and so on.

Comment: How lovely to search around for `x y` and discover that it's simply like `x.y`. How is this making things handier, it's something I don't really get. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the warning that a `y` field is required for a `y_=` field

Comment: as a supplement, `a b c` in pattern match is equivalent to b(a, c), this's the reason why `case a::b => ... ` in list pattern match can work

Answer (score 21):

## Special Classes: Tuples and Symbols

As mentioned by [Rahul G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192247/rahul-g), tuples and symbols get a slightly special syntax.

- Symbols: the syntax `'x` is short for `Symbol("x")`
- Tuples: `(p1,p2,..,pn)` is short for a case class `Tuplen[T1,T2,..,Tn](p1,p2,..,pn)`

For example, the following two are equivalent.

```
val tuple1 = ("Hello",1)
val tuple2 = Tuple2[String,Int]("Hello",1)
```

Comment: This is not unique to tuples and symbols, though: strings, integers, longs, doubles, floats, characters, booleans, functions, XML and `null` also have special literal syntax. In fact, I would argue about whether or not literals are "syntactic sugar" at all. Syntactic sugar is a purely local transformation of code. What are literals being transformed into?

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Jaxkson's answer:

- `type F[A,B]` can be used as `A F B`.

For example:

```
type ->[A,B] = (A,B)
def foo(f: String -> String)
```

- Using `=> type` in a method definition makes the compiler wrap expressions inside the method call in a function thunk.

For example

```
def until(cond: => Boolean)(body: => Unit) = while(!cond) body

var a = 0
until (a > 5) {a += 1}
```

Comment: I didn't actually know about that first syntax, interesting. This is why we need a consolidated page like this.

Comment: Can you give a example for first syntaxt? It will be great help

Answer (score 15):

## Extractors:

There are two methods used for extractors, `unapply` and `unapplySeq`. These are used in multiple variable assignments and pattern matching.

- The first use case is where unapply takes the object it is supposed to match and returns a `Boolean` based on whether or not it matches, for example,

  ```
  trait Gender
  trait Male extends Gender
  trait Female extends Gender
  object Male extends Male
  object Female extends Female
  class Person(val g: Gender, val age: Int)

  object Adult {
      def unapply(p: Person) = p.age >= 18
  }

  def check(p: Person) = p match {
      case Adult() => println("An Adult")
      case _ => println("A Child")
  }

  //Will print: An Adult since Adult.unapply returns true.
  check(new Person(Female, 18))

  //Will print: A Child as it falls through to the _ case.
  check(new Person(Male, 17))
  ```

Honestly, I don't really get the purpose of the above syntax since it can be done almost just as easily by just putting the code in the `case` statements. Of course if you have a better example, leave a comment below

- The general case where `unapply` takes some fixed-number of parameters and returns either an `Option[T]` for a single parameter or a `Option[(p1,p2,...)]` for multiple, i.e. a Tuple with the matched values, for example, continuing from the above code:

  ```
  object Person {
      def apply(g: Gender, age: Int) = new Person(g, age)
      def unapply(p: Person) = if(p.age < 0) None else Some((p.g, p.age))
  }

  //Using Person.apply as described in the Basics section
  val alice = Person(Female, 30)
  val bob = Person(Male, 25)

  //This calls Person.unapply(alice), which returns Some((Female, 30)).
  //alice_gender is assigned Female and alice_age 30.
  val Person(alice_gender, alice_age) = alice

  bob match {
      //Calls Person.unapply(bob), but sees that g is Male, so no match.
      case Person(Female, _) => println("Hello ma'am")
      //Calls Person.unapply(bob) and assigns age = bob.age, but it doesn't pass
      //the 'if' statement, so it doesn't match here either.
      case Person(Male, age) if age < 18 => println("Hey dude")
      //So bob falls through to here
      case _ => println("Hello Sir")
  }

  Person(Male,-1) match {
      //Person.unapply(Person.apply(Male,-1)) returns None because p.age < 0.
      //Therefore this case will not match.
      case Person(_, _) => println("Hello person")
      //Thus it falls through to here.
      case _ => println("Are you Human?")
  }
  ```

**Note:** [Case classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29#Case_classes_and_pattern_matching) do all those `apply`/`unapply` definitions for you (as well as other stuff) so use them whenver possible to save time and reduce code.

- `unapplySeq`. This works similarly to `unapply` as above, except it must return an `Option` of some kind of sequence.

As a quick example,

```
scala> List.unapplySeq(List(1,2,3))
res2: Some[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 7):

Anonymous functions:

`_ + _` is short for `(a, b) => a + b`

Answer (score 7):

Context bounds desugar into `implicit` parameters, e.g. consider a function that leverages the `Monoid` type class:

```
def suml[T: Monoid](xs: List[T]) = {
  val T = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
  xs.foldLeft(T.mzero)(T.mplus)
}
```

where the `: Monoid` part is a context bound, gets translated to:

```
def suml[T](xs: List[T])(implicit evidence$1: Monoid[T]]) = {
  ...
}
```

therefore the following compiles, too:

```
def suml[T: Monoid](xs: List[T]) = {
  val T = evidence$1
  ...
}
```