# How does foo(a)(b) += x work in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have been counting occurences with a mutable map:

```
var bar = collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
```

Now `bar(a) += b` works just fine, no matter if the key `a` is present in `bar` already or not (in which case it will then be added).

I tried the same thing with a mutable map of mutable maps:

```
var foo = collection.mutable.Map[Int, collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]]().
          withDefaultValue(collection.mutable.Map().withDefaultValue(0))
```

How does `foo(a)(b) += x` look without syntactic sugar?

Using [What are all the instances of syntactic sugar in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662984/what-are-all-the-instances-of-syntactic-sugar-in-scala) I would assume it expands to:

```
foo.apply(a).put(b, foo.apply(a).apply(b) + x)
```

But why does this not update `foo` itself accordingly like in the introductory example (i.e. `foo` will not have a dedicated value for key `a` if it wasn't present before)?

**Edit:** As [Perseids pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260564/how-does-fooab-x-work-in-scala#comment28548572_19260729), `foo(a)(b) += x` will change the mutable default value. Is this a desired feature?
Using `getOrElseUpdate` as suggested by [DaoWen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19260729/2860570) seems to be the best way to overcome both problems. But while that works well for functions of type `Int => Int => Int` it becomes really cumbersome for functions of type `Int => Int => Int => Int => Int`. So I'm still happy for any suggestions!

Comment: `foo(a)` (in the first example) and `foo(a)(b)` (in the second example) are both of type Int. And there is no += method in the [Int class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Int).

Comment: absolutely right, I's under the scala-daze effect!

Comment: "_foo(a)(b) += x will change the mutable default value. Is this a desired feature?"_ I think this was designed with immutable objects in mind. It's fine to return the same immutable object as the default value (e.g., an `Int` or an immutable `Map`). It doesn't work so well for mutable values...

Comment: Is it really necessary to use that many levels of nesting in the map? Could you just use a Tuple as the key instead? In other words, instead of `Int => Int => Int => Int => Int`, you'd have `(Int, Int, Int, Int) => Int`.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an issue with `withDefaultValue`, not the `+=` operator. Your first `withDefaultValue` for `foo` returns a new mutable map if the given key does not exist. When you do the lookup `foo(a)(b)`, if `foo(a)` doesn't exist, then it returns a new map, which we'll call `tmp`. `foo(a)(b) += x` then essentially expands to this:

```
val tmp = foo(a)
tmp(b) += x
```

The problem is that only `tmp` is being updated by `+=`, not `foo`. So your update is happening on `tmp`, but `tmp` gets thrown away after the call because it's never stored anywhere.

If you want your parent map to get updated, you might want to look into using `getOrElseUpdate` instead of relying on `withDefaultValue`.

---

***Note:*** As Perseids points out in the comments below, `withDefaultValue` takes a *by-value* parameter. This means that every time you get an unset key from your map, it's going to return **the same mutable map instance!** This is yet another reason you should think about using `getOrElseUpdate` (which uses a *by-name* parameter), or at least `withDefault`, which takes a function. (That's all assuming that you actually want different map instances for each slot in your map...)

Comment: How does this temporal map get generated? The outer `withDefaultValue` only gets a reference to a concrete instance of a mutable.Map, not of a factory.

Comment: I just played a little with the REPL and your explanation does not match my results. I created an Array `val a = Array[Int] (10)` and put that into withDefaultValue `val bar = collection.mutable.Map[Int,Array[Int]]().withDefaultValue(a)`. Now `bar(0) eq a` evaluates to `true`, i.e. bar returns the same original reference to `a` every time a key is not found and _not_ a copy of `a`.

Comment: @Perseids - You're right. I thought `withDefaultValue` had a *by-name* parameter. It won't return a new map each time. I think that's a totally separate issue... I'll update my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

> How does `foo(a)(b) += x` look without syntactic sugar?

It depends on whether or not the object returned by `foo(a)(b)` has a method named `+=` or not. If it does, then it's equivalent to:

```
foo.apply(a).apply(b).+=(x)
```

If it doesn't, then it's equivalent to:

```
foo.apply(a).update(b, foo.apply(a).apply(b).+(x))
```

Except without the duplicate evaluation of `foo.apply(a)` (I think.)