# Where is synthetic sugar for generics with two type parameters (ie. that F[A,B] is equal to A F B) documented?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and I found out that if I have class:

```
class Foo[A, B]
```

Then I can start refering to it as `A Foo B` instead of `Foo[A,B]` like this:

```
var a: Int Foo Double = new (Int Foo Double)
```

I found out about it when learning about `<:<` class, but no one mentions how is this possible to write it down like that and I can't find any documentation regarding this. Where can I find things like this documented?

I've seen question about instances of synthetic sugar and it contains my finding, but it's also only a finding. I'd like to know where in Scala documentation can I find the source.

Mentioned question: [What are all the instances of syntactic sugar in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662984/what-are-all-the-instances-of-syntactic-sugar-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for *Infix Types*, from the [SLS 3.2.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#infix-types):

> An infix type `T1 op T2` consists of an infix operator `op` which gets applied to two type operands `T1` and `T2`. The type is equivalent to the type application `op[T1, T2]`. The infix operator `op` may be an arbitrary identifier.