# What does dot colon colon (.::) mean in Scala?

Tags: scala

Below code adds element to `res` list. My question is how scala internally translates `.::` symbols?

**Code snippet:**

```
var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
res .::= (1, 2)
res .::= (3, 4)
res
```

**output:**

> res56: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2),(3,4))

Comment: The output should be `List((3,4), (1,2))`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few things going on in that snippet. Before diving into it let's talk about the difference between `var` and `val`. Namely, that a variable declared using the `val` keyword is immutable, i.e. its value *cannot* be changed:

```
scala> val x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> x = 2
<console>:13: error: reassignment to val
       x = 2
         ^
```

On the other hand, `var` keyword is used to declare a mutable variable, i.e. its value *can* be changed:

```
scala> var y = "bar"
y: String = bar

scala> y = "foo"
y: String = foo
```

What if we wanted to compute a new value of `y` by appending to its current value?

```
scala> y = y + "bar"
y: String = foobar
```

Sure that works, but it turns out there's a shorthand for doing that:

```
scala> y += "bar"

scala> y
res10: String = foobar
```

By the way, in Scala, `+` is just a name of a method, so `y + "bar"` is the same as `y.+("bar")`. Ugly, but valid. Similarly, `y.+=("bar")` is also a valid replacement of `y += "bar"`.

Great, let's remember that for later. Next, as others have already pointed out, `::` is just a method for *prepending* elements to a list (from Java it can be invoked as `someList.$colon$colon(someElement)`). The important thing to note is that the `::` method *returns a new list*:

```
scala> var letters = List("b", "c")
letters: List[String] = List(b, c)

scala> letters.::("a")
res1: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> letters
res2: List[String] = List(b, c)
```

What if we wanted to set `letters` to the list which contains the letter "a"?

```
scala> letters = letters.::("a")
letters: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Notice that this looks awfully similar to the previous example with strings. Does the shorthand work here too?

```
scala> letters ::= "a"

scala> letters
res6: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Yes, it does. `letters.::=("a")` works as well.

---

Now, let's break down the original snippet:

**Step 1**

Create a variable named `res` and assign it an empty, immutable list. This empty list is intended to contain pairs of integers `(Int, Int)`.

```
var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
```

Here's an alternative way of doing the same thing:

```
var res = List.empty[(Int, Int)]
```

(which, in my opinion, is a bit easier to read)

---

**Step 2**

Prepend a new element `(1, 2)` to list `res` and reassign the resulting list back to `res`.

```
res .::= (1, 2)
```

Or, without spaces:

```
res.::=(1, 2)
```

Looks familiar? We could've also written it out as:

```
res = res.::(1, 2)
```

---

**Step 3**

Prepend `(3, 4)` following the logic in step 2

---

**Step 4**

Print out current value of `res`, which should be: `List((3,4), (1,2))`

---

**Side note**

Confusingly, the compiler is lenient enough to allow us to specify only a single set of parentheses when calling `::`, though we really ought to have two sets: one for the method invocation and another one for indicating a pair of integers. So, there happens to be yet another valid 
way of writing the same thing `res.::=((1, 2))`.

More generally:

```
scala> def first(p:(Int, Int)):Int = p._1
first: (p: (Int, Int))Int

scala> first(6,7)
res0: Int = 6

scala> first((6,7))
res1: Int = 6

scala> first(6 -> 7) //lolz! another one using implicit conversion
res2: Int = 6
```

The implicit conversion is ever-present since it's defined in Predef.[ArrowAssoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html)

mind = blown

I also recommend taking a look at [What are all the instances of syntactic sugar in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662984/what-are-all-the-instances-of-syntactic-sugar-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

## Just method invocation

`.` (dot) used for method invocation on instance of a class.

`::` is a method defined on the `List`

`::` is a method declared in the `List` class which creates instance of `scala.collection.immutable.::` class.

Notice that `::` is a method in List class and also `::` is a final class in the package `scala.collection.immutable`

## Scala Standard library

Here is the implementation of the `::` function in the `List` class

```
@SerialVersionUID(-6084104484083858598L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A]
                                  with LinearSeq[A]
                                  with Product
                                  with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, List]
                                  with LinearSeqOptimized[A, List[A]]
                                  with Serializable {
  override def companion: GenericCompanion[List] = List

  import scala.collection.{Iterable, Traversable, Seq, IndexedSeq}

  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: A
  def tail: List[A]

  // New methods in List

  /** Adds an element at the beginning of this list.
   *  @param x the element to prepend.
   *  @return  a list which contains `x` as first element and
   *           which continues with this list.
   *
   *  @usecase def ::(x: A): List[A]
   *    @inheritdoc
   *
   *    Example:
   *    {{{1 :: List(2, 3) = List(2, 3).::(1) = List(1, 2, 3)}}}
   */
  def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
    new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)

.....
 }
```

Here is how `scala.collection.immutable.::` is defined.

```
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of

```scala
var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
res .::= (1, 2)
res .::= (3, 4)
res
```

should be

> List((3,4), (1,2))

because [the colon colon method ::](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::(x:A):List[A]) adds an element to the front of a list.

**The dot** `.` is totally optional in this case - this is just for specifically stating, that you are calling method `::` on the list object `res`. This means that your code is equivalent to this one:

```
var res = List[(Int, Int)]()
res ::= (1, 2)
res ::= (3, 4)
res
```

Internally **colon colon** `::` is implemented like this:

```
  /** Adds an element at the beginning of this list.
   *  @param x the element to prepend.
   *  @return  a list which contains `x` as first element and
   *           which continues with this list.
   *
   *  @usecase def ::(x: A): List[A]
   *    @inheritdoc
   *
   *    Example:
   *    {{{1 :: List(2, 3) = List(2, 3).::(1) = List(1, 2, 3)}}}
   */
  def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

A new list is created (because of the immutability) with the argument as a first element and the current list content as the rest