# error: value update is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code which throws an error as below. Unable to figure out the problem.

```
val someDF = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
val someDF2 = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "cat"),(-45, "tiger")).toDF("number", "word")
val someDF1= someDF.withColumn("Action",lit("A"))
val max_rows= someDF1.count().toInt
for(i <- 0 to max_rows) {
  if (someDF1("number") === someDF2("number")) {
    if (someDF1("word") === someDF2("word")) {
      someDF1("Action") = "D"
    } else {
      someDF1.unionAll(someDF2.select($"*", lit("D")))
    }
  }
}
```

> error: value `update` is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>
> ```
>               someDF1("Action") = "D"
>                                 ^
> ```

Comment: The error message might be a little bit confusing, because `update` is the desugared method resulting from `someDF1("Action") = "D"`, which is equivalent to `someDF1.update("Action", "D")`. As the error message says, there is no `update`, because datasets are immutable.

Comment: In the duplicate: specifically the fourth bullet point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662998/2707792).

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTyukin. Will look into it

Comment: Instead of loops, I used a join which worked for me..
val cpdf = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
val tabdf = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "cat"),(-45, "tiger")).toDF("no", "word")
val cpdf1= cpdf.withColumn("Action",lit("A"))
val groupedData_col =  cpdf1.as("cpdf1").join(tabdf.as("tabdf"), col("cpdf1.word") === col("tabdf.word") && col("cpdf1.number")=== col("tabdf.no"), "left_outer").filter(col("tabdf.word") isNull).select(col("cpdf1.*"))