# Why there is a different error message on using += and a=x+y on a val variable?

Tags: scala

I had defined a val variable (`t`), and an array(`m`) with Int values and then tried to perform sum of all elements of array using for loop in two ways:
case1. Using `+=` (Error message: value += is not a member of Int )
case2. Using `a=x+y` way (Error message: reassignment to val  )

Error is expected in this case as I'm trying to re-assign a new value to a val variable but why there is different error message in case1 and case2?

```
scala> val t = 0                                                                                                                              
t: Int = 0 

scala> val m = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)                                                                                                           
n: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

case1:

```
scala> for(e<-m) t+=e                                                                                                                         
<console>:28: error: value += is not a member of Int                                                                                          
       for(e<-m) t+=e                                                                                                                         
                  ^
```

case2:

```
scala> for(e<-m) t=t+e                                                                                                                        
<console>:28: error: reassignment to val                                                                                                      
       for(e<-m) t=t+e                                                                                                                        
                  ^
```

Comment: Does the last bullet point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662998) solve your problem?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I don't think that point answers my question. As += (case1) works successfully if I declare the variable "t" as var. Also in the example given at the link - a is an object of type var.

Comment: What's the problem with a snippet of code working successfully? The linked answer explains precisely why `+=` works on an `Int` var. Also, `var` is not a type.

Comment: Maybe I'll summarize it: 1) If `t` is a `val` of type `Int`, then `t += ...` produces an error, because `Int` has no method called `+=`. 2) If `t` is a `val`, then reassignment to `t` is not allowed, because that's the whole point of `t` being a `val`. 3) If `t` is not a `val`, then `+=` is desugared as explained in the linked answer. Every case mentioned so far seems to be precisely described either by the error message itself, or by the linked duplicate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the desugared version of `t += 42` when `t` is a `val`:

```
t.$plus$eq(42)
```

Note how there is no assignment happening, instead, it is simply a method call on `t`. Contrast this with desugared version of `t += 42` when `t` is a `var` and it does not have `+=` method available

```
t = t.$plus(42)
```

Here we see an assignment statement. Therefore, as there is no assignment happening in the case of `t+=e` where `t` is a `val`, the error message does not indicate `reassignment to val`, instead it is complaining about missing method `+=`, that is, `$plus$eq`, on `t`.

Comment: So, `+` desugars into `$plus` at some point. Good. It's not quite clear what the replacement of `+` by `$plus` buys us, exactly.

Comment: `t.$plus$eq(42)` shows there is no assignment happening, which perhaps explains different compiler message.

Comment: Ok, yes...  *"If you invoke method `m` on object `t` with argument `a`, then `t.m(a)` is not rewritten into an assignment"* - That's true, but it leaves too many things implicit. If one doesn't expect that certain methods indeed *are* rewritten into assignments, it reads like a tautological truism. On the other hand, if one already knew that the method `+=` sometimes rewrites into an assignment, then one wouldn't need this Q/A... Maybe you should add the third case (`var t`, `+=`) mentioned in the comments, for contrast.

Comment: 1. I'd suggest either desugaring to `$plus` in both cases or to `.+=(42)` in the first. 2. "when t is a var" That's not correct. If there is a `+=` method, it'll be used for a `var` as well.