# Scala "<-" for comprehension

Tags: scala, loops, compiler-theory, for-comprehension

I have found that Scala always has a "natural explanation" to anything. Always something like "ohh, but that's just a function being called on this and that object with this and that parameter". In a sense, nothing is really compiler-magic as we know it from other languages.

My question is on the ***<-*** operator as used in the following code:

```
for(i <- 0 to 10) println(i)
```

In this example I can see it being rewritten to something like:

```
0.to(10).foreach((i:Int)=>println(i))
```

but this doesn't explain how the ***i*** got carried into the anonymous function inside the foreach function. At the point where you write ***i*** it is not an object, and not yet a declared variable. So what is it, and how is it being carried over to the inside of foreach?

My guess is that I finally discovered something which is in fact *compiler magic*

Thanks for your time.

**To clarify,** my question is: how does the <- operator work in the 1st line of code since i is not an object on which it can be called as a function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`<-` is a language-defined keyword symbol, as is `=>` but in distinct contrast to `->` (which is a defined symbol). Because it is part of the basic Scala grammar, it can be used to create bindings (for the `i` in your example) which is something that cannot be done by user-defined constructs.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. I would suggest you to document this if possible, it is kinda out of the blue right now.

Comment: @Felix: It's documented in the specification. And pretty much every Scala book available in the market covers it.

Comment: oh yeah, i didnt get a book yet. waiting for the definitive 2.8 book

Comment: This is not at all new in 2.8. I only picked up the language in the 2.7 era, but I'm pretty sure it goes back much further, likely to the very beginning of the language.

Comment: Yes...that still doesn't change the fact that I'm waiting for the definitive 2.8 book :-)

Answer (score 64):

To augment Dave's answer, here is a translation schema for 'for-comprehensions' from Scala language specification:

> A comprehension `for (enums) yield e` evaluates expression `e` for each binding generated by the enumerators enums. An enumerator sequence always starts with a generator; this can be followed by further generators, value definitions, or guards.
>
> A generator `p <- e` produces bindings from an expression `e` which is matched in some way against pattern `p`. A value definition `val p = e` binds the value name `p` (or several names in a pattern `p`) to the result of evaluating the expression `e`. A guard `if e` contains a boolean expression which restricts enumerated bindings.
>
> The precise meaning of generators and guards is defined by translation to invocations
>   of four methods: `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, and `foreach`. These methods can be implemented in different ways for different carrier types.
>
> The translation scheme is as follows. In a first step, every generator `p <- e`, where p is not irrefutable (§8.1) for the type of `e` is replaced by
>
> ```
>  p <- e.filter { case p => true; case _ => false }
> ```
>
> Then, the following rules are applied repeatedly until all comprehensions have been
>   eliminated.
>
> - A for-comprehension `for (p <- e) yield e0` is translated to `e.map { case p => e0 }`.
> - A for-comprehension `for (p <- e) e0` is translated to `e.foreach { case p => e0 }`.
> - A for-comprehension `for (p <- e; p0 <- e0 . . .) yield e00`, where . . . is a (possibly empty) sequence of generators or guards, is translated
>     to: 
>   `e.flatMap { case p => for (p0 <- e0 . . .) yield e00 }`.
> - A for-comprehension `for (p <- e; p0 <- e0 . . .) e00` where . . . is a (possibly empty) sequence of generators or guards, is translated to:
>     
>   `e.foreach { case p => for (p0 <- e0 . . .) e00 }` .
> - A generator `p <- e` followed by a guard `if g` is translated to a single generator:
>     `p <- e.filter((x1, . . . , xn) => g )`
>    where `x1`, . . . , `xn` are the free variables
>     of `p`.
> - A generator `p <- e` followed by a value definition `val p0 = e0` is translated
>     to the following generator of pairs of values, where `x` and `x0` are fresh names:
>
>   ```
>   val (p, p0) <- 
>     for(x@p <- e) yield { val x0@p0 = e0; (x, x0) }
>   ```

Comment: Okay, I don't understand everything after first read, but it's interesting :-) Where did you get this?

Comment: @Felix: As I said at the top of the answer, it's from the language specification (can be downloaded from www.scala-lang.org)

Comment: Link to the language specification: https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops

Answer (score 7):

In this case, it really is a bit of compiler magic.  Translation from for-comprehension to filter/map/flatmap form is a special bit of desugaring, much like conversion of the special forms of update and apply methods.