# Scala Future with filter in for comprehension

Tags: scala, filter, future, for-comprehension

In the example below I get the exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not satisfied`

I want to have the result `Future( Test2 )` when the check `if( i == 2 )` fails. How do I handle filter/if within a for comprehension that deals with composing futures?

Below is  a simplified example that works in the Scala REPL.

**Code:**

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f1 = Future( 1 )
val f2 = for {
  i <- f1
  if( i == 2 )
} yield "Test1"
f2.recover{ case _ => "Test2" }
f2.value
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `for-comprehension`, you are filtering by `i == 2`. Because the value of `f1` is not two, it will not yield a `Success` but instead a `Failure`. The predicate of the filter is not satisfied, as your errror message tells you. However, `f2.recover` returns a new `Future`. The value of `f2` is not manipulated. It still stores the `Failure`. That is the reason you get the error message when you call `f2.value`.

The only alternative I can think of would be using an `else` in your `for-comprehension` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192227/how-can-i-do-if-else-inside-a-for-comprehension).

```
val f2 = for ( i <- f1) yield {
  if (i == 2) "Test1"
  else "Test2"
}
f2.value
```

This will return `Some(Success(Test2))` as your `f3.value` does.

Comment: However if f2 fails because of "i <- f1" failing, the result will not be "Test2" but still a Failure.

Answer (score 31):

This is a more idiomatic solution, in my opinion. This predicate function creates either a `Future[Unit]` or a failed future containing your exception. For your example, this would result in either a `Success("Test1")` or a `Failure(Exception("Test2"))`. This is slightly different from "Test1" and "Test2", but I find this syntax to be more useful.

```
def predicate(condition: Boolean)(fail: Exception): Future[Unit] = 
    if (condition) Future( () ) else Future.failed(fail)
```

You use it like this:

```
val f2 = for {
  i <- f1
  _ <- predicate( i == 2 )(new Exception("Test2"))
  j <- f3  // f3 will only run if the predicate is true
} yield "Test1"
```

Comment: In your `predicate` method, you're better off using `Future.successful(())` than `Future(())`

Answer (score 10):

Of course I figured out one solution myself. Perhaps there are better, more idiomatic, solutions?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f1 = Future( 1 )
val f2 = for {
  i <- f1
  if( i == 2 )
} yield "Test1"
val f3 = f2.recover{ case _ => "Test2"  }
// OR val f3 = f2.fallbackTo( Future( "Test2" ) )
f3.value
```

Comment: It is mentioned in the docs as well: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional_composition_and_forcomprehensions no when I take a second look.

Comment: I think using `recover` here is okay.  If you want your recover to only apply to the filter predicate based exception, then you should change the `case _` to `case ex:NoSuchElementException` where `NoSuchElementException` comes from `java.util`.

Comment: Jürgen: This is a six months old question, the code above was an example taken out of a REPL session, so it is geared towards clarity. You're commenting on that you can put parenthesis around statements in Scala? Not seeing what your contribution is here.

Answer (score 0):

I liked @pkinsky 's idea, and made a bit of improvement. I dropped code to create `Exception` object like this:

```
val f2 = for {
  i <- f1
  _ <- shouldTrue( i == 2 )
  j <- f3  // f3 will only run if the predicate is true
} yield "Test1"
```

`shouldTrue` function is implemented using lihaoyi`s [sourcecode](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode) library:

```
def shouldTrue(condition: sourcecode.Text[Boolean])(implicit enclosing: sourcecode.Enclosing, file: sourcecode.File, line: sourcecode.Line): Future[Unit] =
  if (condition.value) Future.successful( () ) else Future.failed(new Exception(s"${condition.source} returns false\n\tat ${file.value}:${line.value}"))
```

Then it automatically generates more meaningful exception message:

```
java.lang.Exception: i == 2 returns false
    at \path\to\example.scala:17
```