# For expression with an if filter causes an error

Tags: scala

How can I refactor my code so I don't have a if statement in my for expression?

I am getting an execution exception with:

```
[NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not satisfied]
```

I am doing a if option is defined below and that is causing the problem:

```
val maybeUserFut: Future[Option[User]] = 
    for {
          usernameOpt <- lookupUsername("...")
          if usernameOpt.isDefined
            userOpt <- getUser(usernameOpt.get)
        } userOpt
```

What pattern should I start using to avoid this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869624/scala-future-with-filter-in-for-comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
for {
  usernameOpt <- lookupUsername("...")
  if usernameOpt.isDefined
    userOpt <- getUser(usernameOpt.get)
} yield userOpt
```

is transformed into

```
lookupUsername("...")
  .withFilter({ usernameOpt => usernameOpt.isDefined })
  .flatMap({ usernameOpt =>
    getUser(usernameOpt.get).map({ userOpt =>
      userOpt
    })
})
```

`Future.withFilter` is defined as ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8f567bc9c01e29624f5b7fcce40a0ee7fe261c08/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L334)):

```
def filter(p: T => Boolean)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] =
  map {
    r => if (p(r)) r else throw new NoSuchElementException("Future.filter predicate is not satisfied")
  }
```

so there isn't a simple transformation that is going to work.

I would probably write something like:

```
lookupUsername("...").flatMap({ usernameOpt =>
  usernameOpt match {
    case None           => Future.successful(None)
    case Some(username) => getUser(username)
  }
})
```

If you want to use `for` comprehension syntax you will need a monad transformer like [Scalaz OptionT](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/235f066f71f37506b486c86e279b60d9b6ff707f/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/OptionT.scala) which abstracts the explicit lift into `Future` (eg `case None => Future.successful(None)`):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scalaz.OptionT._

val maybeUserFut: Future[Option[User]] = 
  (for {
    username <- optionT(lookupUsername("..."))
    user <- optionT(getUser(username))
  } yield user).run
```