# flatmap versus <- in Scala

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala “<-” for comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754089/scala-for-comprehension)

Could someone please explain how the <- operator in Scala works, or at least point me to a link. Someone tweeted a Scala tip: use <- instead of flatmap. Cool but how?

Comment: It's called a [for-comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Scala).

Comment: Apologies, I did not know what it was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for-comprehension (<-) is just a syntactic sugar for composition of multiple collection-like operations (foreach, map, flatMap, filter etc.)

This is a good article that explains what for-comprehensions translate into:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html