# Scala: how to use immutable values returned from function

Tags: scala, immutability

I am new to Scala and try to use it in a functional way. Here are my questions:

1. Why can't I create a new binding for 'cnt' variable with function return value using '<-' operator?
2. How can increment immutable variable in a functional way (similar to Haskell <-) ? For the sake of experiment I don't want to use mutable vars.

   ```
   import scala.io.Source
   object MyProgram {

     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       if (args.length > 0) {
         val lines = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines()
         val cnt = 0
         for (line <- lines) {
           cnt <- readLines(line, cnt)
         }
         Console.err.println("cnt = "+cnt)
       }
     }

     def readLines(line: String, cnt:Int):Int = {
       println(line.length + " " + line)
       val newCnt = cnt + 1
       return (newCnt)
     }
   }
   ```

As for side effects, I could never expect that (line <- lines) is so devastating! It completely unwinds lines iterator. So running the following snippet will make size = 0 :

```
val lines = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines()
var cnt = 0
for (line <- lines) {
  cnt = readLines(line, cnt)
}
val size = lines.size
```

Is it a normal Scala practice to have well-hidden side-effects like this?

Comment: tip: in scala last statement of the function interpreted as result to return, thus `readLines` can be written as `def readLines(line: String, cnt:Int):Int = { println(line.length + " " + line); cnt + 1}`

Comment: Scala encourages use of immutability, you have the option of using mutable data structures in situations like the one you have. You can idiomaticaly fold/reduce/recurse to eliminate var's but they are the underlying mechanisms used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fold on `lines` like so:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines()
val cnt = lines.foldLeft(0) { case (count, line) => readLines(line, count) }
Console.err.println("cnt = "+cnt)
```

Your `readLines` method does side-effect with the call to `println`, but using `foldLeft` guarantees left-to-right processing of the list, so the output should be the same.

Comment: See my addition to original question regarding side-effects in Scala

Answer (score 1):

*Why can't I reassign immutable 'cnt' variable with function return value using '<-' operator?*

Why would you? If you has java experience, <- has the simular meaning as `:` in `for(Item x: someCollection)`. [It is just a syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754568/298389) for taking current item from collection and naming it, it is not a *bind* operator in general.

Moreover, isn't *reassign immutable* [oxymoron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron)?

*How can increment immutable variable in a functional way (similar to Haskell <-)?*

Scala people usually use `.zipWithIndex` but this will work only if you're going to use counter inside for comprehension:

```
for((x, i) <- lines.zipWithIndex) { println("the counter value is" + i) }
```

So I think you need to stick with `lines.count` or use fold/reduce or `=` to assign new value to `var`iable.

Comment: You right, I should not use "reassign" so I have changed my question to: "Why can't I create a new binding for 'cnt' variable with function return value using '<-' operator?" And from answers here I now understand that Scala does not provide programmer explicit binding mechanism for immutables like Haskell monads do.

Answer (score 0):

`<-` is not an operator, just a syntax used in for expressions. You have to use `=`. If you want to use `<-` it must be within the for-iteration-expression. And you cannot increment a `val`. If you want to modify that variable, make it a `var`.