# flatMap and For-Comprehension with IO Monad

Tags: scala, monads

Looking at an IO Monad example from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

```
def ReadLine: IO[String] = IO { readLine }
def PrintLine(msg: String): IO[Unit] = IO { println(msg) }

def converter: IO[Unit] = for {
  _ <- PrintLine("enter a temperature in degrees fahrenheit")
  d <- ReadLine.map(_.toDouble)
  _ <- PrintLine((d + 32).toString)
} yield ()
```

I decided to re-write `converter` with a `flatMap`.

```
def converterFlatMap: IO[Unit] = PrintLine("enter a temperate in degrees F").
     flatMap(x => ReadLine.map(_.toDouble)).
       flatMap(y => PrintLine((y + 32).toString))
```

When I replaced the last `flatMap` with `map`, I did not see the result of the readLine printed out on the console.

With `flatMap`:

```
enter a temperate in degrees 
37.0
```

With `map`:

`enter a temperate in degrees`

Why? Also, how is the signature (`IO[Unit]`) still the same with `map` or `flatMap`?

Here's the `IO` monad from this book.

```
  sealed trait IO[A] { self =>
    def run: A
    def map[B](f: A => B): IO[B] =
      new IO[B] { def run = f(self.run) }
    def flatMap[B](f: A => IO[B]): IO[B] =
      new IO[B] { def run = f(self.run).run }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Scala converts IO[IO[Unit]] into the IO[Unit] in the second case. Try to run both variants in scala console, and don't specify type for the `def converterFlatMap: IO[Unit]`, and you'll see the difference.

As for why map doesn't work, it is clearly seen from the definition of IO:
when you map over IO[IO[T]], map inside will  call `run` only on the outer IO, result will be IO[IO[T]],  so only first two `PrintLine` and `ReadLine` will be executed.

flatMap will also execute inner IO, and result will be `IO[T]` where `T` is the type parameter `A` of the inner `IO`, so all three of the statements will be executed.

P.S.: I think you incorrectly expanded for-comprehension. according to [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754568/1573825), for loop that you have written should be expanded to:

```
PrintLine("enter a temperate in degrees F").flatMap { case _ =>
    ReadLine.map(_.toDouble).flatMap { case d =>
        PrintLine((d + 32).toString).map { case _ => ()}
    }
}
```

Notice that in this version flatMaps/maps are nested.

P.P.S: In fact last `for` statement should be also flatMap, not map. If we assume that scala had a "return" operator that puts values into the monadic context,
(e.g.  return(3) will create IO[Int] that does nothing and it's function `run` returns 3.),           
 then we can rewrite  `for (x <- a; y <- b) yield y` as 
 `a.flatMap(x => b.flatMap( y => return(y)))`,
but because `b.flatMap( y => return(y))` works absolutely  the same as `b.map(y => y)` last statement in the scala for comprehension is expanded into map.

Comment: but we need to use a `flatMap` in the final line of the `for comprehension` due to, as you pointed out, `map` only executes `f(self.run)`, whereas we need `f(self.run).run` (flatMap), right? I understand that both compile since both `IOMonad#map` and `#flatMap` return `IO[Unit]`.

Comment: [also - your example worked (thanks), but it should be `PrintLine((d + 32))...`]

Comment: No, the final line could be a map, as in my p.s., but the rest of the comprehension should be correctly expanded.

Comment: I'm confused as to how `PrintLine((d + 32).toString).map { case _ => ()}` results in calling the inner-most `PrintLine`. It seems that, reading only `map` and `flatMap`'s signatures, only the latter will call `run` on the inner and outer `IO[Unit]`

Comment: There's no inner IO in the `PrintLine((d + 32).toString).map { case _ => ()}` :). It is a single `IO[Unit]` and is itself an "inner" IO. The second flatMap, which is ` ReadLine.map(_.toDouble).flatMap { case d =>` calls `run` on it.