# Scala regex and for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I am trying to reason about how for comprehension works, because it is doing something different from what I expect it to do. I read several answers, the most relevant of which is this one [Scala "<-" for comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754089/scala-for-comprehension) However, I am still perplexed.

The following code **works as expected**. It prints lines where the values matched by two different Regexes are not equal (one for the value in a session cookie and another for the value in the GET args, just to give context):

```
  file.getLines().foreach { line =>
      val whidSession: String = rWhidSession.findAllMatchIn(line) flatMap {m => m.group(1)} mkString ""
      val whidArg: String = rWhidArg.findAllMatchIn(line) flatMap {m => m.group(1)} mkString ""
      if(whidSession != whidArg) println(line)
  }
```

The following is the problematic code, which **iterates on the letters within the matching strings**, thus printing the line as many times as there are different letters in the two values:

```
  /**
   * This would compare letters, regardless of the use of mkString.. even without the flatMap step.
   */

  val whidTuples = for {
    line <- file.getLines().toList
    whidSession <- rWhidSession.findAllMatchIn(line) flatMap {m => m.group(1) mkString ""}
    whidArg <- rWhidEOL.findAllMatchIn(line) flatMap {m => m.group(1) mkString ""} if whidArg != whidSession 
  } yield line
```

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but your second version appears (at a glance anyway) to have a difference from the first version: in the `whidSession <- ...` line, the `mkString ""` part is inside the {} instead of outside as it was in the first case. Bug?

Comment: In first snippet you use regex `rWhidArg` but in second `rWhidEOL`. Maybe your second regex is matching in every symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that corresponding matches are equal:

```
scala> val ss = "foo/foo" :: "bar/bar" :: "foo/bar" :: Nil
ss: List[String] = List(foo/foo, bar/bar, foo/bar)

scala> val ra = "(.*)/.*".r ; val rb = ".*/(.*)".r
ra: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.*)/.*
rb: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*/(.*)

scala> for (s <- ss; ra(x) = s; rb(y) = s if x != y) yield s
res0: List[String] = List(foo/bar)
```

but allow multiple matches on a line:

```
scala> val ss = "foo/foo" :: "bar/bar" :: "baz/baz foo/bar" :: Nil
ss: List[String] = List(foo/foo, bar/bar, baz/baz foo/bar)
```

this would still compare the first matches:

```
scala> val ra = """(\w*)/\w*""".r.unanchored ; val rb = """\w*/(\w*)""".r.unanchored
ra: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (\w*)/\w*
rb: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = \w*/(\w*)

scala> for (s <- ss; ra(x) = s; rb(y) = s if x != y) yield s
res2: List[String] = List()
```

so compare all matches:

```
scala> val ra = """(\w*)/\w*""".r ; val rb = """\w*/(\w*)""".r
ra: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w*)/\w*
rb: scala.util.matching.Regex = \w*/(\w*)

scala> for (s <- ss; ma <- ra findAllMatchIn s; mb <- rb findAllMatchIn s; ra(x) = ma; rb(y) = mb if x != y) yield s
res3: List[String] = List(baz/baz foo/bar, baz/baz foo/bar, baz/baz foo/bar)
```

or

```
scala> for (s <- ss; (ma, mb) <- (ra findAllMatchIn s) zip (rb findAllMatchIn s); ra(x) = ma; rb(y) = mb if x != y) yield s
res4: List[String] = List(baz/baz foo/bar)

scala> for (s <- ss; (ra(x), rb(y)) <- (ra findAllMatchIn s) zip (rb findAllMatchIn s) if x != y) yield s
res5: List[String] = List(baz/baz foo/bar)
```

where the match `ra(x) = ma` should not be re-evaluating the regex but just doing `ma group 1`.