# What does the <- operator do in Scala

Tags: scala

Can someone explain what the <- operator does in scala? I've always seen it used in iterator examples:

```
for(line <- Source.fromFile(inFile).getLines()){
  //do something with each line
}
```

From the examples, its obvious that it does assignment, but how/why is different than normal =? I've searched the docs, but so far have come up empty.

Comment: It's similar to the difference between `<-` and `=` in Haskell, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<-` is the "Generator" operator.  It generates a value from a Range or in your example the iterator.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_for_loop.htm

And this answer might be helpful for details from the Scala specification https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754568/2596497

Comment: Thank you, @Michael. That helps, tremendously.