# scala equivalent of python __getattr__ / __setattr__

Tags: python, scala, dynamic, properties, getter-setter

Is there scala equivalent of python `__getattr__ / __setattr__` (and other `__*__` methods?). Some thing built-in or maybe some traits?

Comment: i don't really know python but do you mean things like getOrElse methods or Scala's Option objects? Both help prevent null pointer exceptions, if that's what you are looking for

Comment: `__*attr__()` are used to control behavior when accessing an object's attributes.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do?  This is way too broad.

Comment: @dhg to add & control "fields" dynamically at runtime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` you’ll have to wait until someone with more insight describes the new Scala 2.10 reflection API. (And of course: it won’t be directly translatable ever. It depends completely on your use case. If you just want a dynamic class, there will be a `Dynamic` trait in the future; if you just want a tiny bit of that, then designing around pattern matching may be an obvious choice.)

As for the multitude of [other `__*__` methods in Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names):

#### Global things

- `__call__` → `apply()` // pretty much identical in behaviour
- `__metaclass__` // use case dependent:

  - currently `class` inheritance or `trait` mixins may be useful
  - in many cases all that metaclass does is instance construction which avoids a call to `super()`; in Scala `super()` is always called in the constructor.
- `__repr__`, `__str__` → `toString()`
- `__eq__` → `equals()`
- `__init__` // implicitly called in the class body
- `__new__` // not directly existent; depending on use case *[early initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initialize)*
- `__del__` // *missing*
- `__nonzero__` // not really, except `implicit def toBool[MyType](a: MyType): Boolean = ...`

#### Container Types

- `__len__` ⇝ `length`, `size` or whatever is the convention in the container
- `__getitem__` → `apply(i: IndexType)` // containers are functions in Scala
- `__setitem__` → `update(i: IndexType, v: ValueType)`
- `__delitem__` // no special handling needed; container convention
- `__iter__` → `foreach(block: ValueType => Unit)` // with return value: `map`, `flatMap`

Notably, `apply` and `update` are *special* in Scala, just as their Python counterparts. They allow for the following Syntax:

```
val x = collection(elem) // val x = collection.apply(elem)
collection(elem) = y // collection.update(elem, y)
```

Similarly, just as Python’s `__iter__` allows a syntax like `(el for el in container)` `foreach` and `map` make it possible to say `for (el <- container) yield el`.

#### Operators

*generally no special handling needed as we are allowed to define those directly*:

- `__add__`, `__sub__`, … // just define `def + (arg: T)` or `def - (arg: T)`

this also includes comparison operators

- `__lt__`, `__ge__` → `def <(other: T)`, `def <=(other: T)`

*however, just as in Python, there are some special cases in the compiler for advanced things:*

- `__radd__`, `__rsub__`, … // right-associative operators; approx. `def +: (arg: T)` or `def -: (arg: T)` (append a `:`)
- `__iadd__`, `__isub__`, … // modifying operators: `def += (arg: T)`, …

#### Context manager

- `__enter__`, `__exit__` // in most cases, a function argument fulfills the same purpose

See also: [List of Scala's "magic" functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483212/list-of-scalas-magic-functions)

Comment: (Is there something wrong apart from the fact that `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` are prominently missing?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's the point here. Scala's uniform access principle means "fields" and methods share the same interface -- because, in fact, "fields" in Scala are getters and setters.

In other words, you can replace them like this:

```
var x: Int = 0

private[this] var _x = 0
def x = _x
def x_=(n: Int) { _x = n }
```

The getter and setter methods will control access to the private field you declared.

Now, if all you want is a way to provide non-static fields, you have to look at the Dynamic trait. It's experimental up to 2.9.2, but it will be available on 2.10, though behind a flag to warn people that this feature is dangerous (because it introduces dynamic typing, but if you don't think dynamic typing is dangerous, you should be fine).

Comment: `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` are not directly related to the uniform access principle in Python (at least not since the `property` decorator has been established).