# A way to simulate indexed access for Class in Scala

Tags: scala

How can I implement a Class which can ask just like Array, providing indexed setter?

like:

```
val k = new MyKls(size)
k(0) = 2  //<<-- I want this kind of functionality.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the `update` method.  If you define this method, then Scala will use it in the `k(0) = 2` syntax.  It is similar to the `apply` method which allows you do use the `k(0)` accessor syntax.

Here's a short example:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

class MyKls(size: Int) {
  val buf = Buffer.fill(size)(0)
  def apply(index: Int) = buf(index)
  def update(index: Int, newValue: Int) { buf(index) = newValue }
  override def toString = buf.mkString("[", ", ", "]")
}

val k = new MyKls(5)
println(k)      // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
k(0) = 2
println(k)      // [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
println(k(0))   // 2
```

You can find some more detail [here](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/08/apply-update-methods.html).

Comment: This question may also be useful in understanding the other special methods: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1483212/547212