# Immutable maps within Mutable maps support Mutable operations

Tags: scala

I was writing some code today when I noticed this quirky behavior. It appears that immutable maps nested within mutable maps allow for the (usually mutable) += operator.

```
scala> val myMutableMap = mutable.Map[String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String]]()
myMutableMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map()

scala> myMutableMap += "outerkey" -> scala.collection.immutable.Map("k1"-> "v1")
res25: myMutableMap.type = Map(outerkey -> Map(k1 -> v1))

scala> myMutableMap("outerkey") += "k2"->"v2"

scala> myMutableMap
res27: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map(outerkey -> Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2))

scala> val huhwhat = myMutableMap("outerkey")
huhwhat: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2)

scala> huhwhat += "k3"->"k4"
<console>:21: error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
              huhwhat += "k3"->"k4"
```

I looked into the Map.scala source, but didn't see any obvious answers to where the += operator could be inherited from.

This is on Scala 2.11.5. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myMutableMap("outerkey") += "k2"->"v2"
```

is being interpreted by the compiler as

```
myMutableMap("outerkey") = myMutableMap("outerkey") + ("k2"->"v2")
```

i.e., create a new map from the immutable `myMutableMap("outerkey")` with the added key `("k2"->"v2")`, and update `myMutableMap` with the new pair `("outerkey" -> <the new map>)`.

This is implemented by `mutable.MapLike`'s [`update` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MapLike.scala#L88), which provides the `foo(x) = y` behaviour. See [this blog post](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/08/apply-update-methods.html) for more info (and there's also an SO answer listing [a bunch of other magic functions in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483212/list-of-scalas-magic-functions)).

Comment: To be more precise: if Scala doesn't find a suitable `+=` (or `-=` …) method, it will retry again with `foo = foo + bar` and use that, if it type-checks. `foo(bar) = baz`, then, in turn, is interpreted as `foo.update(bar, baz)`, it's basically the "setter" equivalent of `apply`.